# I get "no simulations to run" error when I try to reuse a karate DSL test for Gatling performance testing

Tags: karate

At the moment I am creating a POC for Karate-Gatling integration. As we already have many Karate tests it is pretty straightforward to use Gatling for performance testing.

Unfortunately, I always get the no simulation to run error message.

I was searching for a solution both here and in the Q&A section of the Karate DSL Udemy course, but the reason was always a typo. I have checked the code multiple times, even asked my colleague to check it, but I did not notice any typo.

I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Here is the code:
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.adamos.tests.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-api-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <karate.version>1.2.0.RC1</karate.version>
        <gatling.version>1.1.0</gatling.version>
        <gatling.plugin.version>4.1.5</gatling.plugin.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>${karate.version}</version>-->
        <!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-gatling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-gatling</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling.plugin.version}</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gatling.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <simulationsFolder>src/test/java/com/adamos/tests/performance</simulationsFolder>
                    <configFolder>src/test/java/com/adamos/tests/performance/data</configFolder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

SubscriptionsTest.scala

```
package com.adamos.tests.performance.permission_service.subscriptions

import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef.{karateFeature, karateProtocol}
import io.gatling.core.Predef.{Simulation, constantUsersPerSec, scenario}

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

class PerfTest extends Simulation {

//     val protocol = karateProtocol(
 //           //Merging the DELETE calls in the report
 //           "/permissions/subscriptions/{id}" -> Nil
 //   )
    val protocol = karateProtocol()


    protocol.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getHeader("karate-name")
    //protocol.runner.karateEnv("perf")

    //val tokenFeeder = Iterator.continually(Map("token" -> CreateTokens.getNextToken()))

    val create = scenario("Create, read, update, delete subscriptions")
        //.feed(tokenFeeder)
        .exec(karateFeature("classpath:com/adamos/tests/features/permission_service/subscriptions/subscriptions_crud.feature"))

    setUp(
        create.inject(
            constantUsersPerSec(10) during (1 seconds),
            constantUsersPerSec(10) during (1 seconds) randomized,
            constantUsersPerSec(10) during (1 seconds)
            // nothingFor(2 seconds),  //Pause for a given duration.
            // atOnceUsers(5), //Injects a given number of users at once.
            // rampUsers(10) during (5 seconds), //Injects a given number of users distributed evenly on a time window of a given duration.
            // constantUsersPerSec(20) during (15 seconds), //Injects users at a constant rate, defined in users per second, during a given duration. Users will be injected at regular intervals.
            // constantUsersPerSec(20) during (15 seconds) randomized, //Injects users at a constant rate, defined in users per second, during a given duration. Users will be injected at randomized intervals.
            // rampUsersPerSec(10) to 20 during (10 minutes),  //Injects users from starting rate to target rate, defined in users per second, during a given duration. Users will be injected at regular intervals.
            // rampUsersPerSec(10) to 20 during (10 minutes) randomized, //Injects users from starting rate to target rate, defined in users per second, during a given duration. Users will be injected at randomized intervals.

        ).protocols(protocol)
    )

}
```

subscriptions_crud.feature:

```
Feature: CRUD single subscription


  Background:
    * url baseUrl + '/permission-service/v0.1/subscriptions'
    * configure headers = ({'Authorization': tokens.adamosAdminToken})

    # define valid subscription
    * def subscription =
    """
    {
      tenantId: #(credentials.tenantId),
      appId: adamos-client-test,
      enabled: false,
      additionalProvisioningAllowedCallbackUrls: [],
      additionalProvisioningAllowedLogoutUrls: [],
      additionalProvisioningAllowedWebOrigins: []
    }
    """

  @key=ADMQ-1249
  Scenario: get, create, update, and delete a valid subscription as admin
    # create a subscription
    Given param admin = true
    And request subscription
    When method POST
    Then status 201
    # verify created subscription correctness
    And match $.tenant.id == subscription.tenantId
    And match $.app.id == subscription.appId
    And match $.enabled == subscription.enabled
    Then def createdSub = $

    # get created subscription
    Given param admin = true
    And path createdSub.id
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    And match $ contains createdSub

    # update subscription
    * set subscription.enabled = true
    Given param admin = true
    And path createdSub.id
    And request subscription
    When method PUT
    Then status 200
    * set createdSub.enabled = true
    And match $ contains createdSub

    # delete subscription
    Given param admin = true
    And path createdSub.id
    When method DELETE
    Then status 204

    # verify subscription is deleted
    Given param admin = true
    And path createdSub.id
    When method GET
    Then status 404

  # bug https://adamos.atlassian.net/browse/CSA-2693
  @ignore
  @key=ADMQ-1250
  Scenario: Get update and delete non existing subscriptions as admin
    # get subscription
    Given param admin = true
    And path "error"
    When method GET
    Then status 404

    # put subscription
    Given param admin = true
    Given path "error"
    Given request subscription
    When method PUT
    Then status 404

    # delete subscription
    Given param admin = true
    And path "error"
    When method DELETE
    Then status 404

  @key=ADMQ-1251
  Scenario: get, create, update, and delete are disabled for users
    # get subscription
    Given path "irrelevant"
    When method GET
    Then status 403

    # post subscription
    Given request subscription
    When method POST
    Then status 403

    # put subscription
    Given path "irrelevant"
    Given request subscription
    When method PUT
    Then status 403

    # delete subscription
    Given path "irrelevant"
    When method DELETE
    Then status 403

  @ignore
  @delete #called by other feature
  Scenario: delete a subscription by {id}
    # delete subscription
    Given param admin = true
    And path id
    When method DELETE
    Then status 204
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to

1. Add scala-maven-plugin to pom.xml
2. Add Gatling config to karate-config.js

Answer (score 1):

It will be one of these things:

- A typo in the name of the Scala Simulation class
- The package name of the Scala Simulation class not matching
- The build system not able to find the Scala files to compile

  - normally Karate maven projects set `<testResources>` to `src/test/java`
  - `simulationsFolder` should normally be `src/test/java`

Can you please use this project as a reference, start from there and then figure out what you missed: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/examples/gatling

And if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks, Peter! I will do another round. Maybe this time I can find the issue.

Comment: Whenever I specify the simulation folder, will it include all subdirectories? If not, is it possible to include all of them?

Comment: @MiklósSzeles what works for me is `src/test/java` and then please read the docs and try giving the name of the compiled class. please please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/karate-gatling#maven

Comment: There were 2 issues.

1. scala-maven-plugin was not included
2. Gatling config was missing from karate-config.js

Comment: What config do we need to pass karate config for Gatling?

Comment: that's a very general question Deepak. did you try reading the docs ? if you are stuck, follow those instructions on how to submit an issue